# Take user input for number of months back and filter data based on that date

Tags: python, pandas, date, data-science

I am working on a problem where I have to take user input which is an integer indicating the number of months I have to look back at. For example if I want to look at the data 3 months back I must take input from user as 3.
Based on this integer user input I have to filter my dataset.
For example today's date is 8/30/2022 so 3 months back will be 5/30/2022.
Now I want to filter my dataframe to include only those rows for this date which is 3 months back i.e. 5/30/2022

I tried using datetime and relativetime libraries but nothing seems to work for me.

Below is an example of my dataframe:

[id      text1       text2    date
1       Ram         patient  5/30/2022 10:22:00
2       John        patient  5/30/2022 11:45:08
3       Rich        child    5/28/2022 10:45:13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JA1X3.png)

so I want output to be rows corresponding to 1 and 2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYESW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the  `DateOffset` function in Pandas. See the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html) for more details.

An example of this is below which assumes you have a data frame with a date column:

```
num_months = int(input('Please enter the number of months to look back: '))

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
past_date = pd.to_datetime('today') - pd.DateOffset(months=num_months)
df = df[df['date'] >= past_date]

print(df)
```

The above will filter the data frame on the `date` column leaving only those rows where the date is on or after the calculated date i.e. today's date minus the specified number of months.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to show your attempt in future, this feels like I'm doing your homework, but hopefully, this gives you an idea.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3], 'text1': ['Ram', 'John', 'Rich'], 'text2': ['patient', 'patient', 'child'], 'date': ['5/30/2021 10:22:00', '5/30/2022 11:45:08', '5/28/2022 10:45:13']})

user_input = int(input("Enter the number of months to look back: "))
#convert the date column to datetime
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
#set the date column as index
df = df.set_index('date')
#sort the index
df = df.sort_index()
#filter the dataframe to get the rows which are within the last x months
df = df[df.index >= pd.Timestamp.today() - pd.DateOffset(months=user_input)]
#convert the index back to a column
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
#print the filtered dataframe
print(df)
```

Input:

```
Enter the number of months to look back: 12
```

Output:

```
                 date  id text1    text2
0 2022-05-28 10:45:13   3  Rich    child
1 2022-05-30 11:45:08   2  John  patient
```